# Regular Expression Ignore duplicate matches

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string like this :

```
var str = "When Home is on fire go and dance in fire"
```

I want check my string have words `home` and `fire`

For doing this i used this Regex :

```
var words = str.match(/(home)|(fire)/ig)
```

and the output like this :

```
["Home", "fire", "fire"]
```

As you can see `fire` matched twice , i want Ignore duplicate matches and only show for once.

Thanks for Helping.

Comment: Do you need to return `true` if *both* words *exist* in the string? Then use `/\bhome\b.*\bfire\b|\bfire\b.*\bhome\b/i.test(s)`. Or `/^(?=.*\bhome\b)(?=.*\bfire\b)/i.test(s)`.

Comment: @AruneshSingh when i remove g flag output is like this  `["Home", "Home", undefined]` its not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this negative lookahead based regex to make sure to match desired word only if same word doesn't exist further in text thus matching last occurrence of the search words:

```
/(home|fire)(?!.*\1)/ig
```

**Output:**

```
["Home", "fire"]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yF1pK4/7)

Comment: `\1` is back-reference to first capture group `(home)` and `\2` is back-reference to second capture group `(fire)`.

Comment: `/(home|fire)(?!.*\1)/ig`

Comment: @anubhava how would i modify this to work across multiple lines? I.e if the text was
When Home is on fire go and dance in fire
Fire in the hole!

Comment: Use: `/(home|fire)(?![\s\S]*\1)/ig`