# Match numbers in a String only once

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I´ve got this code, but now I´m trying to match numbers only once.

```
var text = "91308543 v1_Printer 91308543 v2 91503362 v1_Printer";
var regex = /9\d{7}/g;

var result = text.match(regex);

var pos0 = result[0];
var pos1 = result[1];
var pos2 = result[2];

return(pos0 + " " + pos1 + " " + pos2);
```

Result is: 91308543 91308543 91503362

Result I want: 91308543 91503362

It is possible to add something to my regex so it doesn´t show duplicate values?
I prefer not to use Arrays because in that case I need to use Native Arrays...

I also have a second question, it is possible to create the variables "pos0", "pos1"... automatically?

Thank you!

Comment: It's possible, but it's better to filter the result array.

Comment: Maybe `(9\d{7})(?!.*\1)`

Comment: Be aware that `"9876511392222332"` will be split in two matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex you are looking for is

```
(9\d{7})\b(?!.*\1\b)
```

It uses [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kkMyIm/1).

The second point is achievable through `eval`:

```
var result = text.match(regex);
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
  eval('var pos' + i + ' = "' + result[i] + '"');
}
```

but this does not help you with the return statement.

You should just use:

```
return(result.join(" "));
```

Comment: Works perfecly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the duplicates after matching, and use a [destructuring assingment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to assign to individual variables:

```js
let text = "91308543 v1_Printer 91308543 v2 91503362 v1_Printer";
let regex = /9\d{7}/g;
let [pos0, pos1, pos2] = text.match(regex).filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i);

console.log(pos0);
console.log(pos1);
console.log(pos2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern `(9\d{7})(?!.*\1)`  negative lookahead .Its not allow the duplicate

[**`Demo regex`**](https://regex101.com/r/0xKTn2/1/)

[**For more reference**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32375217/regular-expression-ignore-duplicate-matches)

```js
var text = "91308543 v1_Printer 91308543 v2 91503362 v1_Printer";
var regex = /(9\d{7})(?!.*\1)/g;

var result = text.match(regex);

console.log(result)
```