# Get whole string enclosed in identifiers if the string is known

Tags: jquery, regex

I have a string, and I need to remove a substring from the string. The substring is enclosed in identifiers (e.x [[1]] substring [[\1]]).

String e.x: `[[1]] abc [[\1]] [[2]] pqr [[\2]] xyz [[3]] rst [[\3]] [[5]] ijk [[\5]]`

I expect to get `[[1]] abc [[\1]]` from string:

`[[1]] abc [[\1]] [[2]] pqr [[\2]] xyz [[3]] rst [[\3]] [[5]] ijk [[\5]]`

if I know the substring `abc`

I have tried this solution: `/\[\[(\d)\]\] pqr \[\[\\\1\]\]/gm` but I need to provide dynamic text.

(e.x if I want to remove `abc`, i need to find the text enclosed in the identifiers in the string and remove it)

Comment: You expect, but you've made no attempt?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: "identifiers" would be `[[number(0-9)]] some text [[\number(0-9)]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslashes in your string need to be escaped otherwise they will be interpreted wrong. `\d` matches a digit, characters such as `[` in regex need to be escaped because they are used for special purposes when not escaped.

```
var string = "[[1]] abc [[\\1]] [[2]] pqr [[\\2]] xyz [[3]] rst [[\\3]] [[5]] ijk [[\\5]]";
var substr = "abc";
regex = new RegExp("(\\[\\[\\d]] "+substr+" \\[\\[.\\d]])");
string.match(regex)[1]; // [[1]] abc [[\1]]
```

Comment: Hi, New requirement: If a number is already used, it cannot be used in another identifier, for ex: if 1 is used already, it can not be used in another identifier. Is this possible inside the regex??

Comment: Please need your help

Comment: I don't know how that would be done with regex, but it may be possible. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32375217/regular-expression-ignore-duplicate-matches) may be similar or possibly another question? You might want to try making a loop through the matches and discarding/flagging ones that include a number you've seen before (add numbers you've seen to an array)? I'd recommend trying things out, looking at related questions, and if it's not working you could create a new question.